# Trouble getting the correct output of code?

Tags: python, cryptography, xor

The original encryption is as follows (which i've already done):
For every letter in the key and every letter in the plaintext ( they are the same length) you compute the ascii values, find the XOR result, convert that to decimal, add 32 to that value and then convert back to char. The char would be the ciphertext. .

`key =  this is a cool key
plaintext =  Wonderland is cool
ciphertext=  C''7e;?a/dc&<lc$*5`

```
def decryption(ciphertext,key):
 plaintext = ""

  for k in range(len(ciphertext)):
    i = ciphertext[k]
    j = key[k]


    val = xor_calc(chr(ord(i)-32), chr(ord(j)-32))
    val = chr(ord(xor)+ 32)
    plaintext += val
```

after decryption im getting:
onderland is cool

obviously should match the original plaintext, additionally with other ciphers and keys im missing letters. My encryption works fine though, as my answers match what the results should be. Any help would be appreciated!

Forgot to mention i have a function xor_calc that takes the cipher and key letters, converts to ascii and computes the XOR results and returns back to char

Comment: She's using `xor_otp` to do the xor. The `+` is for building the plaintext string by concatenation.

Comment: This isn't valid Python.

Comment: @Lizzy, it would help if you posted a complete enough piece of code for us to check. For example, this code has a line which looks like it should be a `def` but is missing some syntax, and it refers to a variable named `plaintext` which isn't declared.

Comment: Have you tried just running your *en*cryption code on the ciphertext & key?  You might be surprised at what you get.

Comment: When I run the code, the output is `'\x97onderland is cool'` - that is, it has the correct length, but the first character is incorrect, instead of missing (as implied in the question). Is it possible that the algorithm works but the ciphertext is incorrect?

Comment: @ScottHunter Nope that doesn't seem to work,  partially because of the shift 32 that I have to do

Comment: @kaya3 encryption cipher text matches the output I'm supposed to have so  it has to be my decryption function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying you calculation of `xor` worked for me:

```
xor = chr((ord(i)-32) ^ (ord(j)-32) + 32)
```

In fact, if I run `decryption(plaintext,key)`, I get your `ciphertext`; if  run `decryption(ciphertext,key)`, I get your `plaintext`.  (This makes sense, since `xor` is reversible.)